# How to activate already opened application when user tries to run it for the second time?

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

I am using Mutex to limit my application to only one instance. This is the code:

```
HANDLE hMutex;
hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, "MyTestApp");

if(hMutex == NULL)
    ShowMessage(GetLastError());
else
    if(GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)  {
        ShowMessage("Application already running!");
        // activate already running instance ?!
     return -1;
    }
```

I would like to expand it to activate the already running instance. How to do it? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "activate"? If it is already running isn't it already active?

Comment: Maybe get a HWND and `SetForegroundWindow`?  You can use `EnumWindows` in that case.

Comment: @Galik By "activate" I mean that the already running instance is shown on the screen even thought it's maybe minimized etc.

Comment: @user9000 I thought of that but new and already running instance have the same caption which could be a problem when enumerating.

Comment: @Tracer then you could compare the HWNDs?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's Win32 application:
1) Use `FindWindow` function with your window name and its class name you gave.
2) Use `SetForegroundWindow` with HWND `FindWindow` returned.

Comment: New and already running instance have the same caption which is the problem when enumerating windows.

Comment: Every time a new instance is runned, check if an instance with such name already exist. If it does, make this one's different, for example adding a number to string that represents the name of window/window class. (std's `stoi` could be useful).

Comment: Just an idea, not really rational way in my opinion.

Comment: Actually, how can it even have a name if you do it before registering class?

Comment: Have the new instance do the enumeration BEFORE it creates its UI, then the enumeration will not find a duplicate window caption.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have determined that no other instance of your application is running, overload the WndProc of your Main form handle a unique message (Like `const unsigned int myMsgId = WM_USER + 100;` for example) or you can use [RegisterWindowMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644947(v=vs.85).aspx). When the 2nd instance of the application starts, broadcast a message with that message identifier `PostMessage(NULL, myMsgId, 0, 0)` before creating the main form and quit. The 1st instance of the app can react to it and bring itself to foreground using [BringWindowToTop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632673(v=vs.85).aspx) (if possible, vista and above do not allow this for obvious reasons). If bringing the app to foreground is not allowed, the status bar icon of your app will start flashing to get the attention of the user.

Sam